# How can one increase the font size when displaying links in Acrobat?

Tags: windows, fonts, adobe-acrobat, accessibility

[image]

I want to change the font size of "https://www.google.com/". The linked text is "short" and the link is "https://www.google.com": I can increase the fontsize for "short" via the `Edit PDF` tool, but I don't see a similar way to increase the fontsize for the link is "google.com" that Acrobat displays when mousing over "short".

Link creation:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 20.12.20041.394260 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF is text-based (PDF from Word, say) and not protected, you can change the text size of an individual element or link.

Open the document, highlight the text, choose Edit Text, and then use the Font/Text bar to enlarge text.

If just a scan (so a picture/graphic) then you cannot change individual elements.

I have Adobe Acrobat DC here and it is working as I describe.

[image]

[image]

Use the Edit PDF function to change Hyperlinks.

Use the Edit PDF from the main toolbar, select the hyperlink, select the text inside the hyperlink area, and change the text size.

All tested here.

[image]

Summary:  Two key points:

1. Use Editable Text in the PDF (not a picture / graphic).
2. Use the EDIT PDF function (main toolbar), select the Hyperlink, then the text inside the Hyperlink selector and edit that. Do not just select text (non EDIT PDF) as that does not work.

Otherwise, I have it all working everywhere I tried.

Comment: I made a Word Doc with the Hyperlink, then PDF'd it, then EDIT PDF as I showed and changed the size in the PDF.  I had saved the PDF, opened it and the larger size still shows as a Hyperlink. Two key points: (1) Editable text based PDF and (2) use the EDIT PDF function (not just select text which does not work for Hyperlinks).

Comment: thanks in https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDWzI.gif the linked text is "short" and the link is "https://www.google.com": I can increase the fontsize for "short" as you suggest, but don't see a similar way to increase the fontsize for the link is "https://www.google.com" that Acrobat displays when mousing over "short".

Comment: So you have it working for one link. That is good. That is as I showed.  Use the EDIT PDF function to get click on the other / any link. That puts a light blue box around it.Now you can select the text inside and change it. That certainly works here.

Comment: Unfortunately only have it working for linked text is "short" but not the link itself "https://www.google.com".

Comment: Try a test document because there may be an issue with your document.  Everywhere I try it, it works.

Comment: Also update Adobe (updates out all the time including today)

Answer (score 0):

From https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-can-one-increase-the-font-size-when-displaying-links-in-acrobat/m-p/12214047#M322670 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210729173436/https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-can-one-increase-the-font-size-when-displaying-links-in-acrobat/m-p/12214047#M322670)), it seems that one cannot increase the font size when displaying links in Acrobat.

Quoting [user try67](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/8023511):

> I don't believe that's possible, unfortunately.